# Returning object from treeset

Tags: java

I have class A consist of name,age,school. class B is groupofstudent and I used treeset as collection since each name will be uniqe. finally I have main class to do some operation.. 
my code work fine for adding, removing and viewing. However, I would like to ask is it possible to search in treeset for specific school and return all objects with that school? if yes how I can do it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Assuming your treeset is organized by student name (your comparable method compares classA.name) then the only guaranteed way would be to iterate through all of the objects in the treeset and check.  Depending on your requirements, perhaps you can choose a better data structure.  Maybe a Map?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to iterate over your Map entries and compare each stored school with the school you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a `TreeSet` can do what you want for this search. You might want to try a `Map<School, List<A>>` that maps each school to a list of objects with that school.